# App won't run in landscape

Tags: android, landscape-portrait, android-7.1-nougat

Today I started trying to optimize my application for landscape mode. But I just cannot get my application to run in landscape mode, there are no settings that I have enabled to force portrait.

I am showing my placeholder screen as an example.

I also double checked that auto rotate in my AVD is **enabled**. I have this problem on every AVD.

Declared like this in my manifest.

```
<activity
        android:name=".PlaceholderActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

My layout looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background_material_light"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true" >

<View
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/feedyr_full" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<include
    layout="@layout/helper_error"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my Theme looks like this.

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

There is also nothing is my class that's forcing portrait

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_placeholder);

    config = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
    model = Model.getInstance();
....
```

[image: My placeholder screen on Nexus 9 running 7.1]

What am I missing?

Comment: check if you have turned off auto rotation on the device .

Comment: Perhaps auto-rotate is disabled on the device?

Comment: Which are the **relevant** settings in your Manifest?

Comment: You mean like this? : <application
        android:name="feedyr.rubenaalders.com.Global"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        tools:replace="android:label"
        android:label="@string/app_name_full"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

Comment: Do other apps run on this specific emulator instance rotate properly?

Comment: Yes. They do. Maybe an important thing I forgot to mention, I have it on every AVD. Doesn't matter if they are started in portrait or landscape.

Comment: press num pad key 7 or 9 to change between landscape and portrait mode .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't ask me why, but suddenly the landscape mode works. I pressed the screen rotation buttons on the right menu. When it went back in landscape it suddenly worked. Did this before so don't know why it suddenly started to work.

I did not change anything in my code, theme, manifest or layout...

[image: AVD in landscape mode]

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `activity` orientation to `sensor` :

```
<activity
    android:name=".PlaceholderActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" 
    android:orientation="sensor"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your AndroidManifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

and in MainActivity.java

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (newConfig.orientation== Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        {

        }
        else  if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        {

        }
    }
```

hope it`s help

Answer (score -1):

Try to enable the emulator screen rotation mode to work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).